# Holographic Image

Tags: optics, interference, hologram

In a holography set-up, as shown in the figure below,  Illumination beam and reference beam both are in phase. The interference pattern generated at the detector contains  the whole information about the object. When illumination beam will incident on to the object its phase and amplitude will change and further object beam will recombines with reference beam at the detector. Question is how the Interference pattern provides complete 3D information of the object ?

[image: Typical Holography setup]

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are many lessons on how holography works on the web. With or without formulae. Please formulate your question on a more specific point.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps answer something like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93566/how-to-understand-holography-and-hologram/99406#99406). Maybe that question helps you also. You have to keep in your mind the proper meaning of *whole information*; the plate will just contain **almost** the same information as the one you get from the other side of a window placed there (**thorugh** it), being its size the same of the plate's one, and provided you are working with the same light source (monochromatic).

***Almost*** comes also from the fact that when reconstructing the *stored image* you have to know the shape of part of the light field used during the recording process (*reference beam*). That's what allows you to *decode* that information.